# OpenCV in Android Studio still memory leak even release()

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, memory-leaks

I am working on OpenCV in Android Studio. I convert RGB to HSV and find that app crash after running 30 seconds. I found that it is beacuase of memory leak and someone say after adding `.release()` and `System.gc();`  will be ok. However, I still get memory leak after adding these two lines.

[The memory profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u95w.png)

My code

```
public class MainActivity extends CameraActivity {

    CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;

    Mat bwIMG;
    cameraBridgeViewBase = findViewById(R.id.cameraViewer);
    cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(new CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
            Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
            bwIMG = new Mat();
            bwIMG.release();
            System.gc();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, bwIMG, COLOR_RGB2HSV);
            image.release();
            return bwIMG;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/android-studio-still-memory-leak-even-release/14943